# MySQL grouped query with OR & AND

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I have two tables, one with data and another one with some values for that data. I need to select all the data, which have values like that:
`(data=1 OR data=2) AND (data=3 OR data=4)`

For each Info ofc there might be many values so it should be `GROUP BY`, but that's all my thoughts about this. I've tried something like this:
    SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.info_id WHERE val IN (1) AND val IN (2) GROUP BY id

Of course it doesn't work, because there is no info with different numbers in one field. Could you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.info_id
GROUP BY id
having (sum(data = 1) > 0 or sum(data = 2) > 0) and
       (sum(data = 3) > 0 or sum(data = 4) > 0)
```

Each expression like `sum(data = 1)` counts the number of rows that match that value, within the rows where `id` is the same.

Note:  this returns the `id`s that match the condition.  To get the original data, you need to join back to the tables.